# Save product images in external table or in JSON column and parse them - PostgreSQL

Tags: node.js, database, postgresql

I'm working on an e-commerce website and there are products and every product has many images related to it.

There is a table called `products` to save the products and every product should have many images, the product images are the links for images uploaded on external storage something like Amazon S3 so I only save the image link in the database and every product should have an array of strings and every string is the product image url.

for example: `["domain.com/images/product_image_1.jpg", "domain.com/images/product_image_2.jpg"]`

I tried 2 solutions to save the product images, and those solutions are working well but I'm confused about which one is better or which one I should follow:

**Solution 1**:
Created a table called `product_images` and this table has 5 columns (`id`, `product_id`, `image_url`, `created_at`, `updated_at`) and storing the images links in it and every product has many images related to it and then creating an API to make the CRUD operations on product images.

**Solution 2:**
Created a column in the `products` table called `images` and set the type `JSON` and saved the images array in it so I can use them directly using the product CRUD APIs.

I don't know which one is the best solution but I think the second solution will be simple and faster
I saw everyone create a second table to save the product images links and join them when fetching the products list or the product details but I think the join will affect the performance and the query time.

Comment: Solution 1 is by far the better. In the long run it is actually easier and generally faster than the other.

Comment: @Belayer Why it's faster than the other? I think joining another table should be slower than having the data in one table right?